# Need help on architecting a multistep wizard using visual force

Tags: visualforce

We are building a 5 to 6 step wizard in visual force where the user is expected to fill up a form on each step of the page.  We plan to use one controller for navigation and 5 visual force pages to handle the input and output fields .Here are things i would need some help.
1. A user can fill the form say 3 steps and abandon and come again later and fill up the form. Has any body done this and if so can you share code snippets or best approach?
2. If a user comes directly and lands on say pag3 of page5, we want the page to check if the form is completed and populate all pages with the data he has filled in. How do we do this?
Any code reference or articles with real examples would really help in this regard?
Thanks
Buyan

Comment: Have you thought up any framework for this yourself? If you have any idea how to do it, add it to your original question and that will give people a better guide on how to help you advance. It will be very difficult to write a guide on creating a multi-step wizard with these specific requirements without something to start with.

Comment: Have you looked at Visual Workflow? http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The force.com cookbook has a great example to get your feet wet creating Visualforce page wizards.

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-wizard-with-visualforce-pages

In order to support partial completion of wizards, you'll need to maintain the state of each record as steps are completed.  You can provide your end users a link to the partially completed record if they want to complete the process later they can copy or save the link.  Alternatively, you could look up partially completed records related to running user, and the next time they access your wizard display this list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My approach has been storing each step in a custom object with an unique id. If the user has an incomplete form, provide him an url to complete the data. How do we store sessionid in a custom object?